# prevent displaying of network interface altname on centos 8

Tags: networking, linux-networking, centos8

When using custom network interface name in Centos 8 an output of `ip a` command starts to show "interface altname".

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: myeth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 82:61:d0:94:fb:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s18
    altname ens18
    inet 192.168.1.224/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global myeth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ee:84:38:d1:3f:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s19
    altname ens19
    inet 192.168.22.3/24 brd 192.168.22.255 scope global eth1
```

**How to prevent creation of these altnames for interfaces?**

Interface altname can be temporary removed using this approach:

```
ip link property del dev myeth0 altname ens18
ip link property del dev myeth0 altname enp0s19
```

But it will be assigned again after reboot.

I was also trying to change `AlternativeNamesPolicy` option to "none" or to empty value in file:
`/usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link`

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6964829

Comment: Thanks. I found that I already tried to change file 99-default.link.
AlternativeNamesPolicy was set to "none". I was also trying to left AlternativeNamesPolicy just empty. After reboot altname appears again.

Comment: In case your question is about parsing this output, then you should use a JSON output and don't bother about these altnames.